# Rx Buffer Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a weird issue with the Rx `Buffer` operator which I can't find a proper solution for and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. If the `Buffer` on line 9 isn't using the `EventLoopScheduler` it starts leaking memory after a while when there are no items being pushed from (`item`)?

The `item` on line 1, is an `IObservable<Entity>` which pushes parsed data retrieved from a TCP socket downstream. Making the `Buffer` use the `EventLoopScheduler` solves the problem but downgrades the overall system performance.

How can this memory leak be solved without having to force the `Buffer` operator to use `EventLoopScheduler`?

```
var groupedItems = items
    .GroupBy(entity => entity._type)
    .Select(o => new {Type = o.Key, Categories = o.GroupBy(entity => entity._key)});

var ev = new EventLoopScheduler();

var collections = from item in groupedItems
    from category in item.Categories
    from entities in category.Buffer(intervalTime, intervalSize, /* ev */)
    where entities.Any()
    select new LogCollection(item.Type, category.Key, entities);

collections.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Where(o => o.Any()).Subscribe(Insert);
```

## Update:

After some investigation, the `Buffer` operator doesn't seem to be the problem other than it "solves" the issue when it is scheduled on the `EventLoopScheduler`. In clear desperation, I've posted the critical code pieces, because I'm fairly new to Rx I do not know If I use the paradigm correctly - So please correct me if I misuse it! :)

Background knowledge: The application retrieves the binary data over a TCP socket and after some transformation inserts it into a database.

#### Receive

Clients can connect to the server and the data sent from the clients will be converted. If any exceptions occurred in the convention, it will catch the exception and disconnect the client.

```
public IObservable<LogEntity> StartListening(IDataConverter converter) 
{
    return Observable.Create<LogEntity>(observer => 
    {
        return _endPoint.ToListenerObservable(_backlog).Subscribe(client => 
        {
            var stream = client.ToClientObservable(_bufferSize, _waitHandle);

            converter.Convert(stream)
            .Catch<LogEntity, Exception>(exception =>
            {
                client.Close(); // dc client
                return Observable.Empty<LogEntity>();
            })
            .Subscribe(observer.OnNext);
        });
    });
}
```

Below is the code which takes care of reading the data sent to the server. The `WaitHandle` is a wrapper around the `EventWaitHandle` and will be blocking if the database goes offline to avoid data being accumulated in the system. (*The problem is observed when the `WaitHandle` is blocking and is not retrieving any data*)

```
public static IObservable<ArraySegment<byte>> ToClientObservable(this TcpClient client, int size, WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    return client.GetStream().ToStreamObservable(size, waitHandle);
}

public static IObservable<ArraySegment<byte>> ToStreamObservable(this Stream stream, int size, WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    return Observable.Create<ArraySegment<byte>>(async (observer, token) =>
    {
        var buffer = new byte[size];

        try
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                waitHandle.BlockingWait();
                var received = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, size, token);
                if (received == 0) break;
                observer.OnNext(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, received));
            }
            observer.OnCompleted();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            observer.OnError(error);
        }
    });
}
```

#### Converter

The converter uses the `Scan` operator to parse the stream of data. Exceptions can occur inside it. Currently, exceptions will propagate up to the `StartListing` method, where the client sending the bad data will get disconnected.

```
public IObservable<LogMessage> Convert(IObservable<ArraySegment<byte>> bytes)
{
    return bytes.Scan(
        new
        {
            Leftovers = new byte[0],
            Logs = new List<LogMessage>(),
        },
        (saved, current) =>
        {
            // Parse bytes
            // Exception here if invalid data retrieved

            return new
            {
                Leftovers = data.ToArray(),
                Logs = logs,
            };
        })
        .SelectMany(o => o.Logs);
}
```

Can you guys see anything which could cause a memory leak? This is basically all the code which takes care of retriving data, converting it before it is sent to the transformation stage (First question). Moreover, I confirmed the memory leak with the dotMemory tool.

Comment: It would be useful if you could let us know how you've determined that you have a memory leak and to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The memory leak has been observed simply by looking at the task manager. After not retrieving any data for approx ~5 sec the memory starts to grow. It seems like it uses up all the tasks available from the task pool. What I find strange is that `EventLoopScheduler` solves the issue. I really would like to share some more code if it could be useful but I don't know where to start, maybe a live session could help? I know you are an expert in this area :)

Comment: The problem with answering this question is that a [mcve] would really help. Do you think you could create a console app that you put in enough code to replicate the issue? I'd start by putting in most of your code and then, once you have the leak, then start simplifying and pulling out code until just before the memory leak goes away - then post that code. We need to be able to copy, paste, then run the code.

Comment: @Enigmativity: As a commented on Lee's answer. I've nearly added the rest of the code in clear desperation to my original question because I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong or if I'm misusing the Rx paradigm. Hope the added code bring some clarity.

Comment: In your updated code you've got a call to `ToListenerObservable`, but I can't see the source.

Comment: Now, for someone who is new to Rx you're doing some fairly sophisticated code. I'm wondering if you've created a situation where adding in any scheduler to `.Buffer` allows the current scheduler to finish its work, but without it the scheduler is never able to get things done. Can you try `Scheduler.Default` instead of an `EventLoopScheduler`, and some of the other scheduler types, and let us know the outcome?

Comment: Missing the point of "Minimal". More code now, and we still don't have the minimal code to compile. I would suggest most of this code is "red herring".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that are notable with your sample code.
Firstly, it is not a MVCE as @Enigmativity points out, e.g. what type is `items`, its values, their properties/(fields?), and same for `LogCollection`.

Secondly, it appears that you are running excessive `GroupBy` operations. This creates a 3deep nesting of observable sequences. I think you want to just `GroupBy` once and lean on anon typing to do the correct thing for you i.e. `.GroupBy(entity => new { entity.Type, entity.Key})`. I say this because once you have grouped by twice, you appear to just unwrap it all again.

Thirdly, you buffer twice. Both time checking for empty buffers. Once using a scheduler (perhaps) and the other not? The second buffer seems redundant.

Fourth, You don't appear to be closing any of your `GroupBy` "windows". This means that for each of these nested groupings, you are creating independent Buffers. Each of which may run on a Thread/Task pool depending on your platform. Thus you are kind of unleashing unrestrained and unknown levels of concurrency into your program. So as each of these new groups are created with new combinations of `_type` & `_key` you are creating new buffer sinks that will never stop/dispose/cleanup and will keep consuming resources.

Fifth, we don't know if your memory issues are just because there isnt enough memory pressure to force a GC thus you are seeing memory pressure climb.

I think your query can be reduced to this:

```
from item in items
group item by new { item.Type, item.Key} into grp
from buffer in grp.Buffer(intervalTime, intervalSize, scheduler)
where buffer.Any()
select new LogCollection(grp.Key.Type, grp.Key.Key, buffer);
```

To cover the issue of memory pressure, I would strongly suggest you providing some way of expiring a group. Even if it was a simple as just killing your subscription after a period of time, and then immediately resubscribing (`Retry` and `Publish` could help here). Otherwise if you get a type/key pair that occurs only once, you will pay the price of a group and therefore the buffer for that for the lifetime of the whole subscription.

Finally, When looking at memory pressure issues, I would suggest actaully capturing or profiling your application instead of glancing at the Task Manager which can send you alsorts of spurious information. Try perhaps `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` or some WMI hooks or even just tracking `GC.CollectionCount` values.

Comment: First of, I would like to thank you for such a great answer! You also taught me a thing or two with the grouping operator. Sadly it doesn't solve the memory leak. In clear desperation, I've added some code pieces for retrieving of data and parsing it. I'm fairly new to Rx, and the issue could be that I'm misusing the paradigm. Please correct me if I have done anything wrong which could cause the memory leak. I would really like to get to the bottom of this! In advance thanks for your help!